# Comparing two strings/buffers in C possibly

Tags: c

The code below is not working. I have been searching for a day now for solution but have surprisingly gotten no where. When i send the word "hello" to the tcp server i would like it to print the text "it works". The problem is on line 97. I will edit title of post once i know whats going on.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 9999 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. And now I will assign a handler for you\n";
        write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
        char *message , client_message[2000];
        //char *contents;
        //contents = "hello";
        //strcpy(mess,contents);
    //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
```

> Problem is below this line

```
        char mess[] = "hello\n";
        if(strcmp(client_message, mess) != 0){
            printf("it works");
        }
    }
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put a comment at the line that fails and explain exactly what the problem is. Cannot really count down 97 lines.

Comment: Here we go with the usual suspects: failure to correctly handle the result returned by recv(). Failure to handle the octet streaming nature of TCP and the assumption that TCP can transfer, on its own, messages larger than one byte. Misuse of strlen()-style calls on char buffers that are not guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: You also assume the client message is NUL-terminated.

Comment: Ok i will give it a shot thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3):

[`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) returns **zero** if the strings are equal. Your condition is incorrect.

You should do `if (! strcmp(...)) printf("it works");` instead of `if (strcmp(...) != 0) ...`

Comment: Thanks that was a indeed stuff up. I had tried a number of statements that stated if strcmp was equal to 0 to display the text however it still didnt work. I can see that my strcmp condition is wrong above dont know how i didnt see that. but the main problem was that strcmp was not working with comparing the two strings. Apart from that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Top hello is "Hello "

While hello near line 97 is "hello\n"

Either:

1) edit one of the hellos

2) use **stricmp()**

Comment: __WHAT???__ Could you please explain this?

Comment: @ForceBru: it's a valid observation. While I believe it may not be the *only* problem, it sure is a good catch.

Comment: I can't see where **client_message** is coming from, however **message** contains "Hello" followed by a space, **mess[]** contains "hello" followed by a linefeed. The best way to get a match is to use **strnicmp(client_message,mess,5);**

Comment: if(strncasecmp(message,mess,5))worked however it only prints "it works" after i close the connection on client side.

Comment: You may need to add **flush();** to explictly write from the client side.

Comment: ok thanks ill give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: 'Hello' looks like a multi-character constant.  Suggest `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
```

[recv Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv)

> All three routines return the length of the message on successful completion.

In this case, you do not ensure that the client_message has a string ending character. Many connections will only send the actual message characters and not the NULL character at the end. You should add (assuming it will fit)

```
client_message[read_size] = '\0';
```

That way the `strlen(client_message)` will be certain to be correct. Alternatively you can use

```
write(sock , client_message , read_size);
```

Since you are repeating the message, the sizes are the same.

Note that if you use the client_message string elsewhere in the code, you should make sure that the '\0' character has been added, just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)